How to find "extra" mutual information

Codewords $00$ and $11$ are sent with equal probability through a BSC with error
probability p. Compute the mutual information between the codeword sent and the first
digit received as output.

I have an idea that if we let $X$ be the random variable of code sent and $Y$ be the random variable of the received first digit then $I(X;Y)=H(Y)-H(Y|X)=1-H(p)$.

Show that the extra mutual information gained on receipt of the
second digit is $H(2p(1 − p)) − H(p)$ bits.

This one I don't quite understand the task. If I let $Z$ be the random variable of codewords received i.e.$\{00,01,10,11\}$ then does it mean I have to find $I(X;Z)-I(X;Y)$?
This is somewhat confusing and I hope someone can clarify. Any corrections or suggestions or full model solution are welcomed.
